# ¿Como extraer data PERL?

Tags: oracle, perl

Estoy haciendo una conexión vía telnet donde me conecto a una maquina y se le ingresa un comando `querydmc id` en donde `id= es un numero`, este proceso se va ejecutando 14 veces por ende va desde el `1 al 14` cada recorrido obtiene información diferente, adjunto 3 ejemplo de como es el resultado:

```
querydmc 1
                        Unit: DMC  1
               Primary State: IS
             Secondary State: 
              FW Load in RAM:        DDM50AK01    
          FW Load in FLASH A:        DDM50AK01    
          FW Load in FLASH B:        DDM50AK01    
                Circuit Pack: NTBN19EA
               Serial Number: FL000MF
         Manufacturer's Date: 06/JUN/2004
Modem:  1  Primary State: IS  Secondary State: 
       DS CP:   5 Spectrum_Chan_Code: 1559
       US CP:  32 Spectrum_Chan_Code: 80
       TX LEVEL: 50 dBmV  RX LEVEL: 15 dBmV
Modem:  2  Primary State: IS  Secondary State: 
       DS CP:   9 Spectrum_Chan_Code: 1551
       US CP:   6 Spectrum_Chan_Code: 80
       TX LEVEL: 50 dBmV  RX LEVEL: 8 dBmV
```

```
querydmc 2
                        Unit: DMC  2
               Primary State: IS
             Secondary State: 
              FW Load in RAM:        DDM20BM01    
          FW Load in FLASH A:        DDM20BM01    
          FW Load in FLASH B:        DDM20BM01    
                Circuit Pack: NTBN19CA
               Serial Number: WZ16REZ
         Manufacturer's Date: 27/NOV/2000
Modem:  1  Primary State: IS  Secondary State: 
       DS CP:   1 Spectrum_Chan_Code: 1503
       US CP:  18 Spectrum_Chan_Code: 94
       TX LEVEL: 51 dBmV  RX LEVEL: 20 dBmV
Modem:  2  Primary State: IS  Secondary State: 
       DS CP:   1 Spectrum_Chan_Code: 1535
       US CP:  16 Spectrum_Chan_Code: 80
       TX LEVEL: 51 dBmV  RX LEVEL: 7 dBmV
```

```
querydmc 3
                        Unit: DMC  3
               Primary State: IS
             Secondary State: 
              FW Load in RAM:        DDM20BM01    
          FW Load in FLASH A:        DDM20BM01    
          FW Load in FLASH B:        DDM20BM01    
                Circuit Pack: NTBN19AA
               Serial Number: Z1A3BYM
         Manufacturer's Date: 22/JAN/1997
Modem:  1  Primary State: IS  Secondary State: 
       DS CP:  11 Spectrum_Chan_Code: 1551
       US CP:  36 Spectrum_Chan_Code: 94
       TX LEVEL: 50 dBmV  RX LEVEL: 15 dBmV
Modem:  2  Primary State: IS  Secondary State: 
       DS CP:  13 Spectrum_Chan_Code: 1551
       US CP:  38 Spectrum_Chan_Code: 80
       TX LEVEL: 50 dBmV  RX LEVEL: 5 dBmV
```

**NOTA: Puede que un `querydmc id` no traiga ninguna información el resultado es el siguiente:**

> >querydmc 4
>
> Specified DMC does not exist.

Lo que he probado:

```
DMC: for my $dmc (1..14)
{
    $t->print("querydmc $dmc");
    my ($pmatch, $match) = $t->waitfor (
        Match => '/>$/'
        , Timeout => $timeout*3 );

    my $modemReached = 0;

    for my $line (split "\r", $pmatch) 
    {
        $line =~ s/\s*\n$//;
        if ($line =~ /^Modem:\s+([0-9]+)\s+(.*)/ || $modemReached > 0) {
            my $modem = $1;
            my $subtitle = $modem ? $2 : $line;

            if ($subtitle =~ /^([^:]+):\s+(\S+( dBmV)?)\s+([^:]+):(.*)/) 
            {
                my $key1    = $1;
                my $value1  = $2;
                my $key2    = $4;
                my $value2  = $5;

                print "$modem\n";
                print "$key1: $value1\n";
                print "$key2: $value2\n";
            }

            $modemReached = 1;
        }
        else {
            my ($key, $value) = split /:/, $line;
            print "$key => $value\n";
        }
    }
}
```

La respuesta que obtengo:

```
querydmc 1 => 
                        Unit =>  DMC  1
               Primary State =>  IS
             Secondary State => 
              FW Load in RAM =>         DDM20BM01    
          FW Load in FLASH A =>         DDM20BM01    
          FW Load in FLASH B =>         DDM20BM01    
                Circuit Pack =>  NTBN19AA
               Serial Number =>  R1AGX1W
         Manufacturer's Date =>  13/AUG/1998
1
Primary State: IS
Secondary State: 

       DS CP: 1
Spectrum_Chan_Code:  1535

       US CP: 2
Spectrum_Chan_Code:  80

       TX LEVEL: 50 dBmV
RX LEVEL:  15 dBmV
2
Primary State: IS
Secondary State: 

       DS CP: 1
Spectrum_Chan_Code:  1559

       US CP: 2
Spectrum_Chan_Code:  94

       TX LEVEL: 50 dBmV
RX LEVEL:  8 dBmV
```

Lo que deseo obtener para guardar en la base de datos:

```
MODEM  |       KEY             |   VALUE 
null      Unit                    DMC 1
null      Primary State           IS
null      Secondary State      
null      FW Load in RAM          DDM20BM01
null      FW Load in FLASH A      DDM20BM01
null      FW Load in FLASH B      DDM20BM01
null      Circuit Pack            NTBN19AA
null      Serial Number           R1AGX1W
null      Manufacturer's Date     13/AUG/1998
1         Primary State           IS
1         Secondary State
1         DS CP                   1
1         Spectrum_Chan_Code      1535
1         US CP                   2
1         Spectrum_Chan_Code      80
1         TX LEVEL                50 dBmV
1         RX LEVEL                15 dBmV
2         Primary State           IS
2         Secondary State
2         DS CP                   1
2         Spectrum_Chan_Code      1559
2         US CP                   2
2         Spectrum_Chan_Code      94
2         TX LEVEL                50 dBmV
2         RX LEVEL                8 dBmV
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que esto debería hacer lo que necesitas:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
DMC: for my $dmc (1..14)
{
  $t->print("querydmc $dmc");  
  my ($pmatch, $match) = $t->waitfor (
                                      Match => '/>$/',
                                      Timeout => $timeout*3
                                     );
  if ($pmatch =~ /Specified DMC does not exist/) {
    next DMC;
  }
  my $modemReached = 0;
  my $modem = 'null';
  my $subtitle;
  printf("%-10s|%-30s|%-30s\n", "MODEM","KEY","VALUE");
  for my $line (split "\n", $pmatch) {
    $line =~ s/\s*\r$//;
    if ($line =~ /Modem:\s+([0-9]+)\s+(.*)/) {
      $modem = $1;
      $modemReached = 1;
      $subtitle = $2;
    } elsif ($modemReached) {
      $subtitle = $line;
    }
    if ($subtitle =~ /^\s*([^:]+):\s+(\S+( dBmV)?)\s+([^:]+):(.*)/) {
      my $key1    = $1;
      my $value1  = $2;
      my $key2    = $4;
      my $value2  = $5;
      printf("%-10s %-30s %-30s\n", $modem, $key1,$value1);
      printf("%-10s %-30s %-30s\n", $modem, $key2,$value2);
    } else {
      my ($key, $value) = split /:/, $line;
      $key =~ s/^\s+//;
      $value =~ s/^\s+//;
      printf("%-10s %-30s %-30s\n", $modem, $key,$value);
    }
  }
}
```

La salida que te da por tu primera respuesta es:

```
querydmc 1
MODEM     |KEY                           |VALUE                         
null       Unit                           DMC  1                        
null       Primary State                  IS                            
null       Secondary State                                              
null       FW Load in RAM                 DDM50AK01                     
null       FW Load in FLASH A             DDM50AK01                     
null       FW Load in FLASH B             DDM50AK01                     
null       Circuit Pack                   NTBN19EA                      
null       Serial Number                  FL000MF                       
null       Manufacturer's Date            06/JUN/2004                   
1          Primary State                  IS                            
1          Secondary State                                                        
1          DS CP                          5                             
1          Spectrum_Chan_Code                        1559                         
1          US CP                          32                            
1          Spectrum_Chan_Code                        80                           
1          TX LEVEL                       50 dBmV                       
1          RX LEVEL                                  15 dBmV                      
2          Primary State                  IS                            
2          Secondary State                                                        
2          DS CP                          9                             
2          Spectrum_Chan_Code                        1551                         
2          US CP                          6                             
2          Spectrum_Chan_Code                        80                           
2          TX LEVEL                       50 dBmV                       
2          RX LEVEL                                  8 dBmV
```